# Symbolic reference files

Tags: git

From man git-config:

> **core.preferSymlinkRefs**
>              Instead of the default "symref" format for HEAD and *other symbolic reference files*, use symbolic links. This is
>              sometimes needed to work with old scripts that expect HEAD to be a symbolic link.

What are the *other symbolic reference* files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source, the setting is only used for the [`create_symref_locked` function](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.9.0/refs/files-backend.c#L2725), which in turn is used primarily for working with HEADs (the local HEAD and remote’ HEADs).

And then there is [`git symbolic-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref), a command entirely for creating these kind of links.

But overall, there doesn’t seem to be many different symbolic reference.

Comment: For what it's worth, I played with making symbolic reference branch names (other than the various `HEAD`s) and they are not very useful.  Some things sort of work and other things just behave very badly.  I have forgotten the details already, but some operations that you might expect to affect the symbolic reference wind up affecting its target instead.